# Configuring multiple domain users for cygwin ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

Can we configure more than one domain users for ssh through cygwin. I am able to configure one, but can other user be configured simultaneously?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Using different credentials/keys?

Comment: Yes @Mario, suppose one domain user is user1, I configured that for ssh. Now I want to configure another domain user user2, which obviously has different credentials. I tried changing permission of /var and /etc/ssh* files to be owned by a group "ssh Users" in domain, which contains both he users as memebers.